# Solve this integral $\int \frac{x-1}{x+4x^3} \, dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I need to solve this integral

$$\int \frac{x-1}{x+4x^3} \, dx$$

As some users suggest me in my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1136192/evaluating-the-integral-int-fracx-1x4x3-mathrm-dx) I used the partial fractions.

and I got:

$$\int \frac{x-1}{x+4x^3} \, dx = - \int \frac{1}{x} \, dx + \int \frac{4x+1}{1+4x^2} \, dx$$

The problem is the second integral, I have tried to separate it in this way:

$$\int \frac{4x+1}{1+4x^2} \, dx = \int \frac{4x}{1+4x^2} \, dx + \int \frac{1}{1+4x^2} \, dx$$

and the final result I get is:

$$-\ln|x| + 4\arctan(2x) + \arctan(2x)$$

But the result is wrong, what am I missing?

EDIT:
I have fixed the `x^2`

Comment: I guess your mistake is in $\frac{4x + 1}{1 + 4x} = 1$.

Comment: Why are there two $\arctan$'s?  One of them should be a $u$-sub to get a second $\ln$.

Comment: There's a typo, the denominators should have $x^2$.

Comment: @Ritz The partial fraction is $$ -  \frac{1}{x} +\frac{4x+1}{1+4x^2}$$

Comment: yes, I fixed it,sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note that $$\frac{x-1}{x+4x^3}=-\frac 1x+\frac{4x+1}{4x^\color{red}2+1}$$ for the second then write

$$\frac{4x+1}{4x^2+1}=\frac12\frac{2}{(2x)^2+1}+\frac12\frac{8x}{4x^2+1}$$

EDIT:

Hence 
\begin{align}
\int \frac{x-1}{x+4x^3}dx&=-\int\frac1x dx+\frac12\int\frac{2}{(2x)^2+1}dx+\frac12\int\frac{8x}{4x^2+1}dx\\
&=-\log x+\frac12\int\frac{d(\tan t)}{\tan^2t+1} \color{blue}{\text{(with } 2x\to\tan t)}+\frac12\log(4x^2+1) \\
&=-\log x+\frac12\int\frac{1+\tan^2 t}{\tan^2t+1}dt +\frac12\log(4x^2+1) \\
&=-\log x+\frac12t +\frac12\log(4x^2+1) \\
&=-\log x+\frac12\arctan(2x) \color{blue}{\text{(with } t\to\arctan 2x)} +\frac12\log(4x^2+1) \\
\end{align}

Comment: yeah sorry, I forgot the x^2 in the question

Comment: ok, I understand $$\frac{1}{2}\frac{8x}{4x^2+1}$$ but not able to understand the first part, can you please explain?

Comment: sure, see the edit.